# Use different library instead of jQuery Mobile for <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, widget

I've looked all over the place to try and find a way to somehow disable jQuery Mobile's selectmenu widget so that I can use a 3rd party library for a `<select></select>`. In my case, I want to use the Chosen library. Is there any way I can do this, while still retaining the rest of the jQuery Mobile styling on my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell jQM to ignore the select by adding `data-role="none"`

```
<select id="mySelect" data-role="none" placeholder="Select an option..." >
    <option value="">Select an option...</option> 
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>            
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>   
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>   
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>   
</select>
```

Here is a demo using the Selectize plugin for the select and other controls use jQM:

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4hfwwxeu/3/)**