# data-native-menu="true" doesn't work in multi select in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to have the native behavior when using mobile with the multiselect button. Desktop can use the normal behavior (`data-native-menu="false"`).

But when using the `data-native-menu="true"`  it just works when disabling jquery mobile with `data-role="none"`.

I am using the chrome browser, also tested with android and windows phone, both with the same error.

Please, find the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/titombo/uxamfLLf/

How to workaround this problem ?

**Possible Workaround**:

1. Wrap around the select with a div with `data-role="content"`, I was getting error because it was inside a `data-role="fieldcontain"`, so everything will be styled as jquery mobile and it will work with the native mobile selects.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/titombo/v5DC3/331/

**Caution**: In browser's it doesn't work.

2. For working with Desktop and Mobile I would add the attributes for `data-native-menu="false"` by checking if is a Desktop browser with `jQuery` and would not add anything if is a mobile. 
   Or in my case that I am using ASP.Net MVC I check with:
3. for using the placeholder I made like this on the initial call:

   $('select span').first().text('Please, select element')

   if (!Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the jQM docs it clearly states:

> Currently jQuery Mobile only supports the multiple attribute on a select with nativeMenu set to false.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/

Comment: @Tito, you would have to use data-role="none" and then style it yourself.  You could also use a third party pluginL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945760/use-different-library-instead-of-jquery-mobile-for-select/30947743#30947743

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just updated the possible solution on the question.